# How can I open a site blocked by the ISP?

Tags: web, modem, isp

I use Linux and connect to the internet with a modem, but many sites are blocked by the ISP in Indonesia.

How can I open a blocked site? It's not a porn site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can find a proxy server that is not blocked, then you can just proxy. search for something like proxy servers accessible from Indonesia. Or you can consider vpn and search for a similar phrase.

If you have a server in another part of the world, then you can also set up your own proxy.

Comment: if there is no way of setting up my connection using the DNS Thanks in advance!

Comment: if they are just blocking the dns lookup, yes, you can just use a different dns server. you can verify if can try the ip of the website to see if that will get you to the page (it will not always work, though, as a lot of web servers rely on the host information, but you should at least get an error page. telnet website/ip 80 can be used to test quickly to see if you can reach the destination.